# What should I return false, exception, etc

Tags: php

I have a method which creates an object of the User class, But If the user is not found I need to return something, but I am not sure WHAT:

```
function getUserById($id)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, email, created, last_active FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($id));

    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) {
        //return what?
    }

    $row = $sth->fetch();
    $user = new User($row);

    return $user;
}
```

And the method should be used something like this:

```
$user = $user_mapper->getUserById($id);
```

The question is how should I handle If the user is not found? Should I use a try catch block and then throw an exception in the rowCount == 0 if statement, or just return false and use a if statement when I set the $user variable to the object?

Comment: i think the return false is enough, tracking for any other methods, let us wait for answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is completely up to you and your error handling philosophy.

I'd decide this based on: *Is this an **exceptional** event? Should this never ever happen?*
If the answer is *yes*, throw an exception. If the answer is *this may happen, I just need to handle this case*, `return false`.

Comment: Maybe consider returning `null`? It tells the whole story (*no* user was found).

Comment: @baž I'd prefer `false`. The return value of a function that returns no value is already `null`, and `false` is generally used to indicate "what you have tried did not work".

Comment: @deceze That's a valid point either. For me a boolean return value is not logical, but it's personal taste :). Just added `null` because nobody mentioned it and your answer was too good to add a new one (I'd have said exception or null).

Comment: Great answer! Now I am just insecure whetever I should choose null or false as return value.

Answer (score 1):

I would return null. This function has a single responsbility : try to find a user according to its id. If it found none, well, it found none, and "null" says exactly that.
After that, it's the code calling this function that should handle the problem.

Now, since you're looking for a user by its id, and not by a login / password, for instance, you should also throw an exception : for there probably is something wrong somewhere in your application : if you have an id, it should be linked to something in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend adding a custom exception handler, as you can have consistent logging methods or ways of feeding back to the user that can be managed from one function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php for some guidance.

So when throwing your exception, try to be descriptive. You can also use `debug_backtrace` to find out the state of execution when the exception was triggered. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php.